# Custom "Sorry, something went wrong" message on SharePoint 2013

Tags: error, error-handling, branding

Could anyone explain me how should I change the default "Sorry, something went wrong" message to some other text or - even better - to change the content of this "component" to something custom?

Where should I look for the files (or where to put these and how to make SP use of these) on SharePoint side?

Thanks!

Comment: You can make a custom 404 page through the UI, not sure if it's the same as 2010 but in 2010 you creates a IHTTPHandler that checked for the error and handled it properly redirecting you to the new error page. I will check my 2013 box and if I find another way I will post an answer.

Comment: Thanks for this. Actually, what I'd like to do is to keep the original 404 page and create custom one for page / web part errors ("Sorry, something went wrong" message) only.

Comment: The iHandler method maybe your best bet then, there are plenty of easy to follow examples on google.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace error pages for WebApplication scope.

To replace custom error page you will need:

1. Create application page for custom page (for ex. error.aspx) and place it to the C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\ directory (for english locale)
2. Then if you prefer powershell run this script to map your page as web application custom error page:

   ```
   $site = Get-SPSite "{site url}" -Limit All
   $spWebApp = $site.WebApplication         
   $spWebApp.UpdateMappedPage([Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication+SPCustomPage]::Error, "/_layouts/1033/error.aspx")
   ```
3. If you prefer code way you could use [SPWebApplication.UpdateMappedPage method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.updatemappedpage.aspx) to map your page.

To get more information and examples check this posts:

[How to customize SharePoint 2010 error pages](http://salvatoredifaziosharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/03/how-to-customize-sharepoint-2010-error.html)

[How to Customize Error Page, Page Not Found and Access Denied in SharePoint 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fabdulwahab/archive/2012/10/02/how-to-customize-error-page-page-not-found-and-access-denied-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

They describe solution for 2010 version but I think it should also work for SP 2013.