# Can I replace "Sorry something went wrong" text with my own custom Text in MySite

Tags: sharepoint-server, mysite

I want to change the error text with my custom text. I am using SharePoint 2013 and MySite. In mysite when any user is not found then a error message is displaying.

The message is  **Sorry something went wrong** with large font size and the main error which is **User not found** is displaying with a link **Technical Details** in small font size.

I want to replace this text with my own text. Please tell me how can I do this, I've done many research on internet and found nothing.

Please help me with proper solution.

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Basically there are a couple ways how to do that:

1. Change the default pages. These are application pages stored in
   /_layouts folder and can be easily modified.
2. Create a new page and assign it via PowerShell (limited to only a couple of the types of pages you can set the URL for):

   `$spsite = Get-SPSite "Site URL"
   $spsite.FileNotFoundUrl = "URL of the Custom Page"`

There is an article which describes that in more depth:

[How to Change System Application Pages (Like AccessDenied.aspx, Signout.aspx etc)](http://geekswithblogs.net/JayantSharma/archive/2012/07/09/how-to-change-system-application-pages.aspx)

And a similar (if not the same question) here on SE: [Custom "Sorry, something went wrong" message on SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/68951/custom-sorry-something-went-wrong-message-on-sharepoint-2013)